# Apply Attributes from CSV to AD Accounts - Extension Attribute

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a script that took AD attributes such as department, manager, office from a CSV and applied them to an AD account name using the for each command. I have changed that script to use the `extensionattribute1` and 2 and it doesn't work.

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Amend.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {            
#Search in specified OU and Update existing attributes            
 Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=example,DC=example,DC=local" |            
  Set-ADUser -Server "domaincontrollername.com" -extensionAttribute1 $($user.extensionAttribute1) -extensionAttribute2 $($user.extensionAttribute2)     
}
```

In my CSV I have going across the top SamAccountName    extensionAttribute1 extensionAttribute2.

I get the error

> ```
> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'extensionAttribute1'.
> ```

Do you guys have any clue why I get this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried full name `ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute1`?

Comment: `-Properties *` is useless since you are not changing or using any properties of the users returned. This should speed up the script as well when it gets removed.

Comment: Not all attributes are parameters in `Set-ADUser`. Use `-Add` when that happens. The question I linked to shows example for changing them. Sorry about the first comment. I read the error wrong.