# Powershell script to update Active Directory attributes of existing users

Tags: powershell

I have a source CSV file with multiple columns, and I want to update some but not all of those columns into the matching user in AD.

```
# Import AD Module             
Import-Module ActiveDirectory            

# Import CSV into variable $userscsv            
#$userscsv = import-csv             
$users = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\ADUPLOADtest2.csv'           
# Loop through CSV and update users if the exist in CSV file            

foreach ($user in $users)
{            
    #Search in specified OU and Update existing attributes            
    Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.Username)'" -Properties * |            
        Set-ADUser -employeeNumber $($user.Emp_Code) -extensionAttribute4 $($user.Cost_Centre) -title $($user.Role) -Department $($user.Work_Area) 
 }
```

Source CSV file example:

```
Emp Code,Username,Surname,Manager,First name,Department,Division,Section,Team,Role,Work Area,Cost Centre
82644,aah,Haven,Peter Jones,April,Executive,Community Wellbeing,General,General,Community Wellbeing Support Officer,Community Wellbeing,50016001
```

Using the code above with the example CSV, I am currently getting the error below on the extensionAttribute4 field update:

[Powershell Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGOmA.jpg)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding and removing extensionattribute to AD object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807496/adding-and-removing-extensionattribute-to-ad-object)

Comment: [Apply Attributes from CSV to AD Accounts - Extension Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41168407/150605) is a better duplicate but has no answers since it was marked a duplicate of [Adding and removing extensionattribute to AD object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807496/150605), so that will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the parameter does not exist. have you tried something like - Set-ADUser -Add @{attributename="TheRequiredValue"}